# How are Universal and Existential Quantifiers Used?

Tags: logic, set-theory, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I’m currently doing a deep dive into logic and am understanding of the concepts, the troubling thing for me is notation. My question is concerning universal and existential quantifiers as they are used in everyday mathematics, opposed to in “formal” predicate logic.

Question:

For example, is
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{N}F(x) $$
the same as
$$\forall x(x\in\mathbb{N}\implies F(x))?$$

And, for example, is
$$\exists x\in\mathbb{N}F(x)$$
the same as
$$\exists x(x\in\mathbb{N}\land F(x))?$$

It seems obvious to me that both are the case but I’ve yet to find any resources that say so explicitly, so conformation would be nice, and if I’m wrong, it would also be good to know. If any such resources exist it would be kind if those were shared too.

Additional questions:

Why; what’s the reasoning?

(I assume for compactness sake, but if there is another more important reason please do let me in on it).

How does this explain the term “such that”?

Comment: Your guesses are correct; and, as to why there is a seeming asymmetry here, see [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4032285/28111).

Comment: For, "there exists $x\in N$ such that $F(x)$", students often mistakenly write something like: $\exists x [x\in N \implies F(x)]$. That it is problematic can be seen when you consider its negation: $\forall x: [x\in N \land \neg F(x)]$.

Comment: Whereas, the negation of $\exists x: [x \in N \land F(x)]$ is $\forall x: [x \in N \implies \neg F(x)].$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, $$\exists x{\in} S\;P(x)$$ is just notational shorthand for $$\exists x\:\big(\,x\in S\ \land P(x)\,\big)\\\text{there exists an $x$ in $S$ }\textbf{such that}\text{ $P(x)$ is true}\\\text{for some $x$ in $S,\,P(x)$ is true},$$ while $$\forall x{\in} S\;P(x)$$ is just notational shorthand for $$\forall x\;\big(\,x\in S\to P(x) \,\big)\\\text{for each $x$ }\textbf{such that}\text{ $x$ is in $S,\,P(x)$ is true}\\\text{every $x$ in $S$ is }\textbf{such that}\text{ $P(x)$ is true}\\\text{for each $x$ in $S,\,P(x)$ is true}.$$

I've deliberately incorporated “*such that*” in both translations, to illustrate that this phrase is not exclusive to the ‘there exists’ quantifier.